# Racket Echo Server/Client hanging

Tags: sockets, networking, client, racket

I'm trying to create a simple echo server and client in Racket.

This is the server:

```
(define (hello_listen port)
    (define listener (tcp-listen port))
    (define (loop)
        (define-values (in out) (tcp-accept listener))
        (thread (lambda ()
                (copy-port in out)
                (close-output-port out)))
        (loop))
    (loop))
```

And this is the client:

```
(define (hello_socket port)
    (define-values (in out) (tcp-connect "localhost" port))
    (write "hello socket world\n" out)
    (display (read in)))
```

The client does not receive any text back, and just hangs on the read.

When I write a simple client in Python however, the behavior is fine:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s.connect(('localhost', 9999))
>>> s.send("hi")   
2
>>> s.recv(500)
'hi'
```

What am I missing here in the Racket client code?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems here:

1. TCP ports in Racket buffer. So in your racket script you are not actually sending the data. The easiest way to fix this is to use [`flush-output`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-buffers.html?q=flush-output#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._flush-output%29%29), but that leads to your second problem.
2. Your server uses [`copy-port`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html?q=copy-port#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fport..rkt%29._copy-port%29%29), which per the docs, doesn't finish until the port closes. So you can either terminate it yourself, or have the client close it using [`close-output-port`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-ops.html?q=close-output#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._close-output-port%29%29) instead.

Which turns your client code into:

```
(define (hello_socket port)
  (define-values (in out) (tcp-connect "localhost" port))
  (write "hello socket world\n" out)
  (close-output-port out)
  (display (read in)))
```

With this change running your client (with your server active) causes the expected behavior:

```
> (thread (lambda () (hello_listen 1337)))
> (hello_socket 1337)
"hello socket world\n"
```